# How to read dynamically created dictionary fashioned keys and values separately in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, dictionary

i have a javascript code which takes data from a csharp function which is returning a dictionary (key-value pair).Now i need to read both the key in one separate array and values in another separate array in javascript.
the javascript code is as follows

**dorendertDictionary = function (data) {
//code to be written here to read the data },**
where data will be dynamically loaded with keys and values....
for instance data will be loaded as follows :
[image]

As i am new to Javascript, was unable to ping the right position.

Comment: `for ( key in dict ) { var value = dict[ key ] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over the key-value pairs, and append each to the respective arrays

```
var dict = {......};
var keys = [], values = [];

for (var key in dict) {
  if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(dict[key]);
  }
}
```

The `foreach` loop can be simplified somewhat by dropping the first block statement:

```
for (var key in dict) if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  keys.push(key);
  values.push(dict[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to understand the format of the function in C# output. SO if the C# function outputs the dictionary in JSON format, you have an easy task ahead of you. Simply say :

```
var dorendertDictionary = function (csharp_output_data) {
    return JSON.parse(csharp_output_data);
};

console.log(dorendertDictionary(csharp_function_output));
```

If it is in another format, you need to write a javascript function to parse that format. Start with the format, then write the javascript function. No problems.